# Used two validations for the same field, But At a particular situation those both errors/validations are occurring. So, How should I avoid 2 err msg

Tags: angular, validation, angular13, angular14

**index.html:**

```
<mat-form-field appearance="outline" class=" w-100">
   <mat-label>CIN Number</mat-label>
      <input matInput formControlName="cinNo" placeholder=""
      (keypress)="validation.noFirstSpaceAllow($event);validation.capAlphaNumeric($event)" maxlength="21">
           <mat-error *ngIf="f['cinNo']?.errors">
               <span class="text-danger" *ngIf="f['cinNo'].hasError('minlength')">Min Length: 10</span>
               <span class="text-danger" *ngIf="f['cinNo'].hasError('pattern')">Invalid CIN Number</span>
           </mat-error>
</mat-form-field>
```

**index.ts:**

```
controlOrgForm() {
    this.organizationForm = this.fb.group({
      cinNo: [this.data ? this.data.cinNo : '',[Validators.pattern('^[A-Z0-9]*$'), Validators.minLength(10)]]                                                       
    })
```

My issue is: If I put cin no. having a length of less than 10 and if the same cin no. is invalid according to the pattern, I get both  errors at a time.
What should I do to avoid this situation?

Comment: A very similar question already exists and I think the CSS-solution is quite nice: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51806607/i-want-to-display-one-error-at-a-time-with-reactive-forms-and-angular-material

Answer (score 0):

If you want to print 1st one error once, then you have to add two conditions in the first error message. Take a loot at below code.

```
<mat-form-field appearance="outline" class=" w-100">
   <mat-label>CIN Number</mat-label>
      <input matInput formControlName="cinNo" placeholder=""
      (keypress)="validation.noFirstSpaceAllow($event);validation.capAlphaNumeric($event)" maxlength="21">
           <mat-error *ngIf="f['cinNo']?.errors">
               <span class="text-danger" *ngIf="f['cinNo'].hasError('minlength') && !f['cinNo'].hasError('pattern')">Min Length: 10</span> // Add both conditions here by giving '!' for last condition to display 1 message
               <span class="text-danger" *ngIf="f['cinNo'].hasError('pattern')">Invalid CIN Number</span>
           </mat-error>
</mat-form-field>
```

I guess this should solve your issue, let me know if anything required.

Answer (score 0):

There another approach using a custom form validator

Imagine a function like

```
  lengthAndPatternValidator(length:number,pattern: string|RegExp)
  {
    return (control:AbstractControl)=>{
      const error=Validators.maxLength(length)(control)
      if (error)
        return error;
      return Validators.pattern(pattern)(control)
    }
  }
```

You can define your FormControl like

```
control=new FormControl('',
           this.lengthAndPatternValidator(10,'^[A-Z0-9]*$'))

//or using FormBuilder

this.organizationForm = this.fb.group({
    cinNo: [this.data ? this.data.cinNo : '',
           [this.lengthAndPatternValidator(10,'^[A-Z0-9]*$'))]]
})
```